# Getting past the security prompt in outlook 2003 via 3rd party software i.e sas

Tags: vba, outlook, sas, outlook-2003

I'm trying to automate the security prompt in outlook when I try to send emails via a 3rd party software i.e SAS. What solutions are there? I've tried a VBA solution and reduced security to low on the tools - macros setting but no joy :(

Comment: just curious, do you get the same "security prompt" when e-mailing a workbook from within Excel?

Comment: Do you have to go via outlook? Can you configure SAS to use your smtp service directly (server-side) instead? E.g. http://support.sas.com/kb/19/767.html (this is for an old version but should be basically the same)

Comment: Carolina, do you mean send file as attachement?

Comment: http://www.everythingaccess.com/tutorials.asp?ID=Outlook-Send-E-mail-Without-Security-Warning is the vba solution I was hoping to try but doesnt work.

Comment: Another solution is to use http://www.snapfiles.com/get/clickyes.html solution

Comment: SASfrog, thanks I'll take a look into your link

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the first warning message that an external program is trying to access Outlook you can save drafts of messages without any hassle (at least using VBA).  I used this to produce whatever emails I needed then ran a seperate macro INSIDE Outlook to send all the drafts.

Or you could use an Outlook macro to communicate with the external software and send it's own emails based on an output.